# Do not compile java files from specific source folder

Tags: java, eclipse

We have some unit tests that check different file types and their contents. 
Among other file types we check .java files. 
Problem with eclipse:

1. File is located at src/test/resources/some/long/path/testfile.java
2. File contents is read as a resource during unit test execution
3. Eclipse reports various java problems including wrong package, etc.

I can't just exclude src/test/resources folder or src/test/resources/**/*.java files from source folder because I need those files as resources during test execution.

If I do that and try to run unit test from eclipse, this file is excluded from classpath and my test doesn't see it.

I can't tell eclipse NOT to try to compile those java files and treat just as resource files same as for other file extensions.

The only option I see, when I right click on java file or source folder, is "ignore optional compiler problems", but it doesn't work because those compile errors are not optional.

Ofc I can try to change file extension to something like "testfile.fakejava", but the point is that unit test has specific business logic tied to file extension.

I can try to set up filter for problems view, but I'll see error icon in project explorer, package view, etc.

Comment: In the _Java Build Path_ the `src/test/resources` must be a source folder with the option `Excluded` set to `**` to copy also `*.java` files unchanged to the output folder instead of copy the compiled `.class` files to the output folder.

Comment: As I already mentioned exclusion doesn't do the job because this way file is excluded completely as it never existed and I can't open it as a resource with smth like getClass().loadResourceAsStream("my.java")

Comment: There are two kinds of exclusion and you choosen the wrong one (completly excluded from the project instead of only excluded as Java source code).